# Complex tori without nontrivial meromorphic function admits no divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I can show that for "generic" lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb C^n$ for $n\ge2$, the complex tori $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ has only trivial meromorphic function. I want to deduce that on such tori, there is no divisor.

There is such an argument in Georges Elencwajg and Otto Forster's paper [*Vector bundles on manifolds without divisors and a theorem on deformations*](https://eudml.org/doc/74563).

[image]
See the second paragraph. Probably it is a well-known fact, but could someone give me some hint or reference? I appreciate it.